# Can I use ‘km/S’ for ‘km/Stunde’?

Tags: usage, abbreviation

> km/hour = km/Stunde

Can I say *km/S* in German to mean km/hour?

Comment: https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilometer_pro_Stunde#Umgangssprache

Comment: It looks like in German people use `km/h` for `km/stunde`

Comment: You can say/write it, but nobody will understand you.

Comment: Kah-Em Schrängstrich S wird man sicher nicht sagen. Geht es ums Schreiben oder ums Sagen?

Comment: It should be noted that **S** is the SI unit symbol for *Siemens* (conductivity) and thus should never be combined with another SI unit if the intended symbol meaning differs. *Std.* would be the normal abbreviation for *Stunde*, but one does not usually mix abbreviations and unit symbols in a formulaic context (i.e. *km/Std.* is unusual and cumbersome; *km je Std.* works, even if it looks old-fashioned). People understand **h** = *Stunde* very well.

Comment: JFTR, you cannot use _k.p.h._, _kph_, _kpS_, _kpStd_ or something like that either if you want to be understood. Colloquially, you can use _Sachen_ for the velocity of a car, though, or omit the unit altogether.

Comment: @Crissov *I bin mit 5 Sachen durch die Kinderspielzone gebraust!* :-D Usually you use *Sachen* if you went real fast, not for speed in general.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Indeed, and omitting the unit altogether also requires a minimum of 20, but maybe that depends on context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The international standard, at least for the SI system, is m/s and this is the standard followed by the German. But km/h is also frequent, especially in non-scientific contexts. In spoken German we often say "kmh" while meaning Kilometer pro Stunde or Kilometer je Stunde. I've never seen km/S as the SI unit for time is s for seconds but sometimes Stunde is abreviated std or st. But none of these are in use in this context.

So to sum up you can use km/h but not any other form which i have treated here.

Comment: Maybe I should use `km/st` or `km/std` in written German?

Comment: So you meant that in German people use `km/h` in place of `km/stunde`?

Comment: Definitely `km/h`. When spelled out, we say "Kilomenter pro Stunde". (You will also often hear "Stundenkilometer", although this is simply wrong when talking about km/h)

Comment: @Tony you'd better use km/h anything else wouldn't be understood.

Comment: @Tony People *write* `km/h`. People *should say* `Kilometer pro Stunde`. But some people wrongly say `Stundenkilometer`. People also say `k.m.h` (ka em ha).

Comment: Actually, _Stundenkilometer_ is not “wrong” grammatically because it follows one of the many possible schemes for compound nouns in German, but there’s a conflicting one – preferred in physics – which implies multiplication, e.g. _Newtonmeter_ N·m.

Comment: @Crissov As a *word* it is grammatically correct, I agree, but so are *Toastbrot* and *Apfelbaum* and neither of them denotes a valid unit for speed. I wonder why people in England or the US are able say *miles per gallon* (and nobody ever says *gallonmiles*) but for us Germans it is so hard to use the correct unit *kilometer pro Stunde*...

Comment: @Crissov In mathematics and physics "Stundenkilometer" would mean `km*h` instead of `km/h`. You get this unit by multiplying a time and a distance. A telephone company could make the price of international telephone calls dependent on the product of the distance and the time. When you call someone in Brazil (distance = 9000 km) and the phone call lasts 30 minutes the product of distance and time would be `4500 Stundenkilometer`. (Note that in this case the word "Stundenkilometer" would probably not be used.)

Comment: @Tony ... however 90% of all persons understand "Stundenkilometer" this way (km/h). Talking about speeds I would say at least 80% of all Germans would say either "Stundenkilometer" or just "Kilometer". Even on official German traffic signs you often can read `20 km` when actually `20 km/h` is meant.

Comment: @MartinRosenau etc.: All native speakers understand _Stundenkilometer_ just fine, even those who don’t want to. In a true physics context, where the restricted technical jargon is appropriate, one would be using m/s anyway (and nobody says _*Sekundenmeter_). As with fuel consumption, it’s also sometimes a matter of perspective: I’m driving at 120 km/h – a) How far will I get in 2 hours? or b) When will arrive at my destination 180 km away?

Answer (score 3):

Can you do it? Yes, you can! And you already did it.

But language is not only a matter of the sender. It's also a matter of the receiver. So the much more important question is:

**Will anybody understand what you mean?**

And here the answer definitely is:

### No.

Most people will not understand you, and those who understand you will be confused.

---

Language in all of its features is a big (and not always logical) collection of general agreements, and one of this agreement is about the units of speed.

There is a scientific standard which is »meters per second« or »Meter pro Sekunde« in Geman, and you write it as »m/s«. But you rarely use it in daily life.

In daily life you measure speed when you drive a car, and in a car you are not interested in how far you can travel within just one second. You are thinking in minutes and hours. But when you use minutes, then you get distances of about 1000 meters or 1 kilometer, but this gives unwieldy numbers of meters or kilometers.

So you measure the distance that you can travel within one hour. Unit-symbols are abbreviations of latin names, and the hour is »hora« in latin. This is why »h« is the scientific symbol for »hour«.

When you use the metric system, you count kilometers per hours, and the symbol for this unit is everywhere on this planet »km/h«.

If you use the angloamerican system, then you use miles per hour (mph), but here the *h* is not derived from latin »hora«, but from english »hour«. This is because mph is not a scientific unit, and because it is only used in a small number of countries, where everyone speaks English.

Here are the symbols and names in Latin, English and German:

- s = (pars minuta) **s**ecunda, second, Sekunde
- m = (pars) **m**inuta, minute, Minute
- h = **h**ora, hour, Stunde
- d = **d**ies, day, Tag
- a = **a**nnus, year, Jahr

In the last example you can see, that the unit symbols are not derived from english names, but from latin names.

<sub>»pars minuta« is in english »small part«. It means a small part (1/60) of an hour.</sub>
<sub>»pars minuta secunda« means »2nd small part«. It means that the small part (minute) a second time is divided into even smaller parts.</sub>

---

When you use the unit »km/h« in a German sentence, then you pronounce it in one of this ways:

- k.m.h. ([ˈkaː.ɛmˈhaː])
- Kilometer pro Stunde
- Stundenkilometer

The last one (Stundenkilometer) is wrong if you measure it by means of science, but language sometimes doesn't care about scientific rules. Language is a collection of common agreements, and many people agree, that *Stundenkilometer* is a valid term for km/h, so they use it. (Some other people disagree and don't use it, but they still understand it. Some of them also begin a discussion and tell you that it's scientifically wrong, but they still understand it.)

Comment: I'm in the last group of people you mentioned - I'll never use *Stundenkilometer* in a real-life conversation and I'll always correct you if you use it in my presence, but I still understand what you're trying to say. I wonder how many US-americans would accept *gallonmiles* instead of *miles per gallon*. It's a bit like you, who answers every "can I use/can I say/Is this a word"-question with a "Yes you can, you already have, but nobody will understand"... :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can not use *km/S* for kilometres per hour in German in no context.

The abbreviations for time durations are:

- Sekunde: s, Sek.
- Minute: min, Min.
- Stunde: h, Std.
- Tag: d, –/–
- Jahr: a, –/–

There is always one scientific one which agrees to the worldwide scientific standard (even if the SI units only contain the second as a defined unit). These are taught at school and especially those for second, minute and hour are in common usage. There are also commonly used abbreviations of the German words. They are sometimes also used. Note how there is no abbreviation <strike>*S*</strike> for *hour*. It would confuse people as it is not expected.

Now you could always say ‘okay, then I’ll just define it at the beginning of my text and it’s good.’ Well yes, you could, but bear in mind that *km/S* is very, very similar to *km/s*. I’ll admit, the latter is probably not used much outside astronomic contexts (and I do have a slight interest in astronomy, so I probably come across it more often) but it just suggests itself so much more to anybody reading the sequence of letters. And 1 km/s is about 80,000 km/h, you really don’t want to mix them up.

So do yourself a favour and stick with the established abbreviations, *km/h*, *Kilometer pro Stunde* or *Stundenkilometer* (the last one only in common speech/nonscientific texts).